# Trying to enable Fielddate on textfields

Tags: elasticsearch

Every time I execute an aggregation command involving a text field, I get an error saying I need to enable Fielddate on textfields. Here's the query i'm executing:

```
GET customers/external/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_date": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The official error that I am getting is:

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [city] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
```

So I try to enable Fielddata by executing this query:

```
PUT customers/external/text
{
  "properties": {
    "city": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

Afterwards, I try to execute the aggregations query, but it still displays the same error message. I then try to execute this query:

```
PUT customers/external/text
{
   "text": {
      "properties": {
        "publisher": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I then execute the aggregations query, but it still displays the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query to enable field data looks wrong to me. I've created a minimal example including `GET customers/external/_mapping` calls to check the actual mapping:

```
PUT customers/external/1
{
  "city": "San Francisco"
}
PUT customers/external/2
{
  "city": "San Antonio"
}
GET customers/external/_mapping
PUT customers/_mapping/external
{
  "properties": {
    "city": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
GET customers/external/_mapping
GET customers/external/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_date": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city"
      }
    }
  }
}
DELETE customers
```

BUT this example also shows why you probably don't want to do that — you have two hits on "san" and that doesn't make much sense. Check out the docs why you probably want to [use a `keyword` for this functionality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata).